# Count number of applications that received a decision by their category?

Tags: sql, oracle

My table has 4 columns in it.

status: (This is a string that is either pended, accepted, or rejected value of P, A, or R)
source:  (this is a code like BBQ5)
id: (this is a unique identifier number)

So a row would be something like

Accepted GBBG 2109202

I want to order them by how many got accepted/ rejected / pended per source

I came up with this.

```
SELECT status , count(status)
FROM myTable
WHERE source in  (
'BB5',
'GGG',
'FEV'
)
GROUP BY status
```

this gives me the number of rejected count but I need it specified per code is this possible in sql ?

Comment: I do not believe that the code you posted actually works. It should give a syntax error.

Comment: hello fixed the code.

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected result. It's not clear to me what exactly you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a case when for the Status categories

```
SELECT 
source,
sum(case when status='accepted' then 1 end) accepted_count,
sum(case when status='rejected' then 1 end) rejected_count
FROM myTable
WHERE source in  (
'BB5',
'GGG',
'FEV'
)
group by source
```

Comment: this solved it thank you very much sir!